# Sending mails using Mandrill PHPmailer is not working

Tags: php, email, mandrill

I want to use Mandrill for sending my emails. I am customizing my phpmailer which I had used to send the mail with mandrill phpmailer. (found here: http://help.mandrill.com/entries/23737696-How-do-I-send-with-PHPMailer- )

```
require 'mandrillmailer/class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mandrillapp.com';                 // Specify main and backup server
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // Set the SMTP port
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'MANDRILL_USERNAME';                // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'MANDRILL_APIKEY';                  // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Your From name';
$mail->AddAddress($to);  // Add a recipient


$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $message;
echo $mail->Subject;
//$mail->Send();
//$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo 'hiii';
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}
else{
    echo 'hello';
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
die('here');
```

I am not getting response messages i.e mail is sent or not. I debugged where it is getting stuck by echo statements. I can see the messages till `echo $mail->Subject;` but not beyond that. I am guessing that `$mail->Send()` is not working that's why messages beyond that are not displaying and email sending is not working.

How do I fix that?

Comment: What is `$mail->ErrorInfo` returning?

Comment: @Grokify: I can't say. It was in the code that the link above provided i.e from the official site. I guess that is for showing the errors information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've put in the proper authorization, try it by requiring the autoloader rather than phpmailer class. This worked for me:

`require 'mandrillmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';`

Alternatively you  could try something a little easier. Something like the official [Mandrill PHP client](https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mandrill-api-php/) or a separate service like [sendwithus](https://github.com/sendwithus/sendwithus_php).

Comment: @ Dylan Moore: Thanks for the help. Its working. But I have a doubt. Could you please tell me why its not saying that mail is received from mandrillapp.com or like something in the mail that received? And also in the sent mail box why its not showing the mail that has been sent?

Comment: Check the [outbound](https://mandrillapp.com/activity) section in Mandrill – you'll see if your emails went out. What do you mean by "why its not saying that mail is received from mandrillapp.com…" ? Do you expect the mailer to tell you? If you're looking for something like that, I suggest using Mandrill's PHP client.

Comment: @ Dylan Moore: ok. I tried first with the small demo code of mandrill mailer and then the above try which I had customized with my webpage. When I first tried that time in sender's sent mail box and mandrill's outbox both shown the mail. At receiver email I had seen the sender's name that I had mentioned like this _John via mail10.wdc04.mandrillapp.com_. Now in above try mail is shown in outbox not in sender's sent box and also not showing that _via mail10.wdc04.mandrillapp.com_ at receiver's inbox.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you expect… It sounds like you need to verify your domain in [Mandrill](https://mandrillapp.com/settings/sending-domains)

Answer (score 0):

First of all check the PHPMailer class version If Its below Version 5 then use the latest version 5.2.9
My issue resolved as I used the Version 5.2.9